display port not working ubuntu 22.04
so I recently got a new cybergeek mini pc which came with ubuntu 22.04.5 installed and the hdmi port works fine, but when I tried to connect a second monitor using the dp port, nothing happens, I am using a brand new dp-hdmi converter and a new hdmi cable so I don't think either of those is the issue. the about section of the settings says this about the graphics card "RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.57, 6.8.0-49-generic)" I am very completely new to linux and to code in general, please let me know if I left out any information you may need, and also how to find that information, just in case.
I did look for answers on others questions but every suggestion I found was about updating nvidia drivers which isn't what my pc has.
